# @Html.DropDownList unable to add form-control class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, form-control

I need to add a class to a DropDownList so it looks more presentable. Therefore, I'm using the code below with `htmlAttribute`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", "Select a Department:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I'm getting errors because it says:

```
does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

Can someone teach me how to add form-control class to do DropDownList?

Code that is working:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: If you already have code that's working, is there a question anymore?

Comment: There is no overload of `DropDownList()` that accepts 2 string parameters and `IDictionary<String, Object>`. The second one works because there is an overload that has the second parameter as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which you pass as `null`

Answer (score 2):

There is no overload of `DropDownList` that lets you specify both a default option as well as HTML attributes. `DropDownListFor` does, however.

How are you populating your dropdown list with options? If you are doing it server-side in your controller action, you can (and probably should) use `DropDownListFor`:

```
@model DepartmentViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentId, Model.Departments, "Select a Department:", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Your view model class would be like:

```
public class DepartmentViewModel {
    ...
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Departments { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    ...
    var model = new DepartmentViewModel();
    model.Departments = new List<SelectListItem> {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "First Department"},
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Second Department"}
    };
    ...
    return View(model);
}
```

But if you're populating the dropdown list with values via javascript/jquery, it would be just as easy to use regular HTML syntax:

```
<select name="DepartmentId" id="DepartmentId" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select a Department:</option>
<select>
```

Comment: Isn't this method hard-coding the values into the DropDownList? I have a sql server database, and i wish to populate my DropDownList with it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The hard-coded values were just a way to demonstrate how to populate a view model. In reality your list of departments would be retrieved dynamically from your database using an ORM like Entity Framework or Dapper.

Comment: That's weird, because today I'm using `@Html.DropDownList("storeSelect", new SelectList(Model.SelectableStores), "- Select the Store -", new { @class = "form-control" })` and it's working great!